# jqGrid with my custom search

Tags: jqgrid

I every one i need to something like as shown in the attachment[image]

Can any one help me out. I dont want to use tool bar search and default search of jqgrid.
Thanks.

Comment: You can insert custom new field like this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077196/jqgrid-simple-searching-with-additional-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct your question you can solve your problem by adding [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) to the `colModel` item which corresponds "Related To" column. The `searchoptions` should has `sopt` property with the operations which you need to allow for the column. For example

```js
searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }
```

Comment: Thanks but i want  my own dropdown over their. how to do that ?

Comment: @JigneshMistry: What sense has to write "your own dropdown"? Do you want to have another texts as the operation names? In the case you can overwrite there with `$.jgrid.search.odata = ['equal', 'not equal', 'less', 'less or equal','greater','greater or equal', 'begins with','does not begin with','is in','is not in','ends with','does not end with','contains','does not contain'];` or modify the corresponding texts in your copy of `grid.locale-en.js`.

Comment: See the images above. you will find over there. seee the left side of the grid. I want to put over there my own dropdown.

Comment: @JigneshMistry: I don't understand what you mean. **What** you want  to put over there your own dropdown? "Custom dropdown" say almost nothing. What is the origin of the information which you want to have? What you want to display?